# Remove islands from geographic regions

Tags: plotting, regions, geography, geographics

I wish to get only the continental parts of countries when using GeoGraphics, for instance in

```
 DiscretizeRegion[GeoGridPosition[Entity["Country", "France"]["Polygon"], "Mercator"]]
```

[image]

I'd like to remove Corsica.

Comment: What did poor Corsica ever do to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the "continental part" of a country is the one with the largest area, you can use `ConnectedMeshComponents` and `RegionMeasure`:

```
countryname = "France";
components = ConnectedMeshComponents[
    DiscretizeRegion[GeoGridPosition[Entity["Country", countryname]["Polygon"], "Mercator"]]];
TakeLargestBy[components, RegionMeasure, 1][[1]]
```

[image]

Trying it out on other countries:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only country that I've found that doesn't really work is Malaysia, for which Peninsular Malaysia is probably the proper "continental part" even though it's geographically smaller than East Malaysia (on the island of Borneo.)

Comment: Great. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

A country is divided into `AdministrativeDivisions` for which `Entity` data is available.

```
divisions = CountryData["France"]["AdministrativeDivisions"]
```

[image]

Each of these administrative divisions has a polygon.

```
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Corse", "France"}]["HasPolygon"]
```

> True

It should be a simple matter of taking a `RegionUnion` of the polygons except for what has to be deleted. Unfortunately, I had to adopt another route as it didn't work for "Provence-Alpes-Cote-d'Azur, France" region. I will start a separate post about it.

---

```
main = Delete[divisions, 
  Position[divisions, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Corse", "France"}]]]

g1 = GeoListPlot[Polygon[main]]
```

[image]

Instead, I extracted and combined polygons from the `GeoListPlot` directly (takes over a minute to run):

```
mainland = RegionUnion@g1[[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]]
DiscretizeRegion[main, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.3]
```

[image]

For countries spread over many islands, this may be a better approach as deleting regions from a list can be routinely achieved. In the output above smaller islands can be deleted using the `ConnectedMeshComponents` method shown in the answer by Michael Seifert.

Comment: That's a nice approach. Thank you so much.