# Polygon for "Provence-Alpes-Cote-D'Azur, France"

Tags: regions, geographics

While answering [168996](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268996/remove-islands-from-geographic-regions) about "removing islands from geo regions", I made a few observations about the polygon associated with "Provence‐Alpes‐Cote‐d'Azur, France". The ideas was to remove a named administrative region (or more of them) and combine the rest of the polygons to make a new region.

With administrative divisions as follows:

```
divisions = CountryData["France"]["AdministrativeDivisions"]
```

[image]

The region calculations happen quickly for `Most` regions. For instance, two regions of Brittany and Normandy can be combined.

```
r3 = Region@
  GeoGridPosition[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bretagne", "France"}][
    "Polygon"], "Mercator"]

r9 = Region@
  GeoGridPosition[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Normandy", "France"}][
    "Polygon"], "Mercator"]

RegionUnion[r3, r9]
```

[image]

For the last region, the calculation takes a minute and returns the following image.

```
r13 = Region@
  GeoGridPosition[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"ProvenceAlpesCoteDAzur", 
      "France"}]["Polygon"], "Mercator"]
```

[image]

Furthermore trying to union this with the region right above it results in an output with a few small islands. More importantly, the calculation seems to be triggered again for `r13`.

```
r1 = Region@
  GeoGridPosition[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"AuvergneRhoneAlpes", "France"}][
    "Polygon"], "Mercator"]

RegionUnion[r1, r13]
```

[image]

**Question(s)**

1. Is this a bug?
2. Can this behavior be replicated on other versions?
3. Is there an alternate source for a correct geo polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provence-Alpes-Côte-d'Azur is made up of 18694 coordinates in 9 polygons. A trial and error approach showed that removing polygon #4, which contains 4 points covering the island of Sainte-Marguerite, allowed the `Region[]` call to display the region as expected (I can't figure out why!).

```
geoPos13 = 
 GeoGridPosition[
  Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"ProvenceAlpesCoteDAzur", "France"}][
   "Polygon"], "Mercator"];
geoPos13[[1]][[1]][[4]] = Nothing;
r13 = Region@geoPos13;
r1 = Region@
  GeoGridPosition[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"AuvergneRhoneAlpes", "France"}][
    "Polygon"], "Mercator"];
Show[r13,r1]
```

[image]
[image]

But now there is another problem. It seems that `RegionUnion[]`is showing a truncated image of the region (this is why I used `Show[]` in the above). Any suggestions?

```
RegionUnion[r1, r13]
```

[image]

Comment: The thing I discovered from your post is to not use `Region` before retrieving the polygons else it takes the extra time I mentioned in the post (only for this region though).  Regarding the truncating upon `RegionUnion`, that is something I have not seen before. Thanks for your effort and pointers.